# Doing side work no LLC - what to do on W9 form?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, self-employment, w9

I am doing some work for on the side for my former employer.  They pay me via an application called [square](https://squareup.com/us/en) that I use.

Its the end of the year so I asked them for a 1099 / W2 and they sent me a W9 form to fill out.

At the top of the W9 is this:

[image]

Its section 3 asking for a classification.  As this is not really a business, I'm just doing work as a contractor what do I enter here?  Do I simply select "Other" and if so do I need to enter in anything?  I ask because I am already working at my current full time job at a different company.  I am only helping my prior company out and they are paying me via the square application (which is basically via credit card).  I charge an extra fee since it is basically credit card as square is charging me fees when I do this so it makes up for the fees.

What do I enter here if this is not really a corporation / trust or an LLC?  You can read this thread that I posted from prior asking a question when I first started helping them:

[How to handle taxes by using credit card app (Square)](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/116624/how-to-handle-taxes-by-using-credit-card-app-square)

Comment: You're an **individual**, right?  So check the *Individual* box.

Comment: @RonJohn - Yes I misread that sorry...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing work is "a business" even if you do it under your own name.

The default category if you haven't done any paperwork to form a company is "individual/sole proprietor".

Both terms fit doing work under your own name, depending on whether you look as the contractor as yourself (an individual) or as a small business entity whose sole proprietor is you.

Comment: So I would check the first one...I misread that one I believe you are right.  I looked at it only paying attention to the LLC portion...but it does say Individual...